# Möbius strip parameterization and charts

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, parametrization

A parameterization of the möbius-strip is given by :

$$\begin{align}M=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x &= \cos t(1+ s\cos(t/2)),\\
y &= \sin t(1+ s\cos(t/2)),\\
z &= s\sin(t/2), \\
t &\in[0,2π],s \in (−1/2,1/2) \}\end{align}$$

Given the parametrization of the möbius strip I need to find two charts that cover $M$. Can someone give me a hint on how to find those $2$ charts ? Is it possible to restric the parameters t and s so that two charts cover the manifold ? My problem is with the $t=0 , \pi\; $I could choose $(0,2\pi)\times(\frac{-1}{2};\frac{1}{2})\; $ for the first chart but how do I cover the edge at $t=0,\pi \;$ with the second chart.

Comment: Hint: You may as well allow $t$ to be an arbitrary real number. Even though not every $t$ lies in $[0, 2\pi]$, your parametrization is $2\pi$-periodic in $t$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang So I could choose $t \in (-\pi,\pi)  $ and $t \in (\pi,3\pi)$ for my two charts

Comment: Those are "the same" chart (since they "differ by $2\pi$"), but $(-\pi, \pi)$ and $(0, 2\pi)$ work. :) (Incidentally, "$2\pi$-periodic" wasn't quite the right description; the important thing is, an open interval of length $2\pi$ in $t$ covers the entire surface minus a line segment.)